# How to display CCITT Group 4 TIFF files in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, tiff, libtiff.net

According to [How to Convert TIFF to JPG Inside Silverlight, client side, using a control or a class/function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1923140/249690) I tried to port LibTiff.NET library to Silverlight, but failed.

I will be very grateful if someone explain me how to remove unsupported by Silverlight without losing opportunity to decompress CCITT Group 4 TIFF files.

Comment: You cannot run unmanaged code in the Silverlight sandbox.  Done.

Comment: If you want to go for an affordable 3rd party control to view TIF files natively in silverlight, then do have a look at http://www.tiffviewer.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LibTiff.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) 2.0 supports Silverlight natively (we've just released it).

Source package of the library contains Silverlight Test Application that may help you.